# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes with Ivy Bridge Processor

Tags: 12.04, kernel, 64-bit, freeze, packaging

My machine with an Ivy Bridge CPU is stable under Windows 7 but freezes in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit. The freezing appears to occur randomly. I read somewhere that kernel 3.3.6 fixes the Ubuntu freeze issue. Any idea when this will be available in 12.04?

Specs:

- ASRock Extreme3 Motherboard with i5-3570K processor (no overclocking)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Gigabyte GA-H77-D3h Motherboard and an i5-3570 CPU.
Freezing occurred on both, the 32-bit and 64-bit Versions of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Updating the kernel to 3.4.0 fixed this issue for me. The system has run without any crashes for several days know.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with my CPU (i7 Ivy Bridge 3770).

Try using kernel versions 3.2.0.24 or before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a 3770 on an ASUS P8Z77-M. The most recent BIOS update fixed the problem after the most recent kernel did not.